# Hibernate Static Method For Entity Operations

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am building a web application using Struts2 and hibernate, along with Spring for dependency injection into the action classes. I am trying to determine if static methods for selecting, updating, and inserting into the database are a good move. If a utility class was to be used it would contain static methods that would act as wrappers for hibernate sessions similar to the following.

## First Option - Static Methods

```
public static <T> T getEntity(Serializable id, Class<?> klass) {
    Transaction txn = null;
    Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    T entity = null;
    try {
        txn = session.beginTransaction();
        entity = (T) session.get(klass, id);
        if (entity == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException(String.format("row {} could not be found in the database.", id));
        }
        txn.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        log.debug("Exception encountered while retrieving {} from the database. Message: {}", id, e.getMessage());
    } finally {

    }
    return entity;
}

public static void updateEntity(Object entity) {
    Transaction txn = null;
    Session session = getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession();
    try {
        txn = session.beginTransaction();
        session.update(entity);
        txn.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        log.debug("Object {} could not be updates.", entity);
    } finally {

    }
}
```

An interceptor would be used to open and close the hibernate session on each request.

```
public class HibernateInterceptor extends MethodFilterInterceptor {

@Override
protected String doIntercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws    Exception {
        JPAManager.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        String result = invocation.invoke();
        JPAManager.getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

The static methods of the utility class should be thread safe because each object that is passed to the methods is local to the thread and hibernate sessions are thread safe as well. If I were using a session variable however that would be a problem but that's not an issue local to just static methods. The downside to using static methods though is they cannot be overridden by a future implementation and are thus concrete in their functionality. In addition, this might encourage lazy design practices where it's just too easy to call the static methods leading to all kinds of dependencies across the layers.

## 2nd Option - Instance Methods

The methods of the JPAManager class would no longer be static and an instance of the class would be injected into the Action classes via spring. Future implementations could override the functionality by extending the class or I could write it as an abstract class and provide the implementation class to Spring for injection. I like this approach better for scalability and long term maintenance. The hibernate entities could be passed into a Business Delegate class, perform the operations and before returning the action result, the instance of JPAManager updates the object, etc.

```
public String execute(){
    //perform business logic on entityObject
    this.jpaManager.updateEntity(entityObject);
    return "success";
}

public JPAManager getJpaManager() {
    return this.jpaManager;
}

public void setJpaManager(JPAManager manager) {
    this.jpaManager = manager;
}
```

I would like to know which option is best as this is my first time implementing all three frameworks into one solution.

Comment: Spring is about dependency injection. Dependency injection is great, because it allows injecting mock dependencies in tests, and thus make the code easily testable. Static methods would ruin this. Dependency injection also allows AOP: Spring can inject a transactional proxy wrapping your bean rather than the bean itself, and thus allows dealing with transactions in a purely declarative way: you just annotate your bean/method with `@Transactional`, and Spring opens and commits the transaction for you. Don't manage your transactions as you're doing.

Comment: Thank you for the response. In my quick review of `@Transactional` and your explanation, my understanding is that methods annotated with     `@Transactional` will manage the automatic opening and commit of hibernate transactions for me so my methods need only grab a session, perform the select, update, or insert and the proxy method will be handled by Spring. Using that approach would you recommend a DAO layer for the entities with `@Transactional` annotations on the methods; or is my JPAManager class with methods annotated with `@Transactional` enough to cut down on boiler plate code?

Comment: You don't understand either transactions nor spring DI. Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: The transactions should be managed at the service layer, not at the DAO layer. Most of the time, a service uses several DAOs, and needs to do all that in a single transaction.

Comment: IMHO this question should be closed as POB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should thinking about rollback too.

`catch (HibernateException e)` — using only `HibernateException` here is not correct.

> hibernate sessions are thread safe

It is not a correct statement.

Some approaches worth to learn

[Currently recommended usage patterns for Hibernate](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/orm.html#orm-hibernate)

[HibernateTemplate and HibernateDaoSupport](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/classic-spring.html)

[Spring Generic DAO And Generic Service Implementation](http://www.codesenior.com/en/tutorial/Spring-Generic-DAO-and-Generic-Service-Implementation)

[Spring Data JPA Tutorial](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/spring-data-jpa-tutorial/)

[The open session In View Anti-Pattern](https://plus.google.com/+VladimirLadynev/posts/gRDyh8r5yoV)

If you want an example, how to implement bicycles like yours, you can refer [my library](https://github.com/v-ladynev/fluent-hibernate).

Comment: Links about nothing that is also outdated.

Comment: @RomanC Looks like, _clayton rogers_ wants to invent an own new approach :) So why don't be familiar with previous ones, even is outdated.

Comment: ough yeah, waiting for him.

Comment: I'm not going to accept the answer just yet. I'd like to see if others weigh in.

Comment: @claytonrogers don't care about others you are not captain on this ship. Did you here about generic approach? Seems you missed a lot from [struts2 plugins](https://struts.apache.org/docs/plugins.html).

Comment: @Romanc what are you talking about? Captain of the ship? I have not heard of generic approach with regard to struts but I will certainly look into it.

Comment: @claytonrogers Who is captain  of the ship? What do you know about struts? Nothing?

Comment: @v.ladynev Ough a big latency in time

Comment: @v.ladynev If I tell him the best approach, what he will do how do you think? Frankly the opinion is not his :)

Comment: @RomanC I think, a good approach to work with Hibernate doesn't still exist yet (I don't consider DAO approaches as good ones). Anyway, It will be interesting to see your answer with the best approach. And, I think, answer to your question: he will accept it :)

Comment: @v.ladynev May be but it never happens in the my best SO practice :0

Comment: @RomanC "Frankly the opinion is not his?" I am having a hard time following you here, most likely because English doesn't appear to be your first language. If you want to offer an answer then by all means put forth your best effort.

Comment: @v.ladynev I am accepting your answer because after reading the links you provided about the older style of implementing using the DAO and DAO service, it lead me to the solution I will use which is Spring's Data JPA. This solution will cut down on the boiler plate code associated with DAO and DAO services.

Comment: @claytonrogers Thank you. You can take a look at Spring Boot too.